# How to get _value of two tables into one table?

Tags: grafana, flux, influxdb-2, flux-influxdb

I'm trying to create a dashboard where i can filter data by gas station location and fuel type.
This is my Table from this query:

```
from(bucket: "homeassistant")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["entity_id"] == "tankerkoenig_aral_tankstelle_bat_waldmohr_e5")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "city_str" or r["_field"] == "value")
  |> aggregateWindow(every: v.windowPeriod, fn: last, createEmpty: false)
  |> yield(name: "last")
```

[flux database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBNFr.png)

How can i get the _value of _field "city_str" and the _value of the _field "value" into one table so i can query the location and the price at the same time within grafana?

Answer (score 0):

Use [schema.fieldsAsCols](https://docs.influxdata.com/flux/v0.x/stdlib/influxdata/influxdb/schema/fieldsascols/) function. You will get one table with `city_str` and `value` columns.

```js
import "influxdata/influxdb/schema"

from(bucket: "homeassistant")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["entity_id"] == "tankerkoenig_aral_tankstelle_bat_waldmohr_e5")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "city_str" or r["_field"] == "value")
  |> aggregateWindow(every: v.windowPeriod, fn: last, createEmpty: false)
  |> schema.fieldsAsCols()
  |> yield(name: "last")
```